# Removing current product from Up-sells products section

Tags: product, ce-1.9.0.1, collection, product-collection, collection-filtering

I am editing "You may also be interested" section (Up-sells products section) in the Product Detail page. I need to remove the current product from "You may also interested" section.

Up-sells products section displays the current product of category product (which most viewed). But I have issue when I go to "You may also be interested" section on product detail page; the current product is also getting displayed on this. I just need to remove the current product from "You may also be interested" section.

Example:
I have 4 products in Up-sells section:

> Test1, Test2, Test3, Test4

I am getting this but when I go to Test1 product detail page, then I need **to not display** Test1 under "You may also be interested" section.

Here is the code I've used so far:

```
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    //->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('neq' => $product_id))
    ->addViewsCount()
    ->joinField('category_id',
    'catalog/category_product',
    'category_id',
    'product_id=entity_id',
    null,
    'left'
)
    //->addAttributeToFilter('category_ids',array('finset'=>$category_ids))
    //->addCategoryFilter($category)
    ->setStoreId($storeId)
    ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
    //
    ->setPageSize(4)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $category_ids ));

Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($products);
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($products);
```

Comment: Please take your time to accept an answer if it helped you. http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

The method`addIdFilter()` of the product collection has a second parameter "exclude" that inverts the filter:

```
$collection->addIdFilter([$product->getId()], true);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am Getting answer Without change Query of Magento.

```
foreach ($products as $_item) {

    $myid =  $_item->getId();

    if ($myid !=  $product_id) {
        <?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>
    }
}
```

I found this solution here: [most view product](http://myphpinformation.blogspot.in/2015/09/magento-get-most-view-products-of-current-prodcut-categories-detail-page.html)